# Puppeteer LaunchAsync Hangs Without Opening Browser

Tags: .net, chromium, puppeteer-sharp

I have a .Net application that uses PupperteerSharp to navigate to different web pages, I have only one browser running at a given time and once that browser process is completed, it's closed before opening a new browser

Previously I had the PuppeteerSharp **V2.0.4** and I recently updated to PuppeteerSharp **V10.0.0** and now it's hanging after while when trying to launch a browser, Once the application started it runs for a while and after opening and closing few browser instances, it hangs at the `await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync()` method.

I'm Running this on Windows 11 build version 22621.1702.

The Chromium version I'm currently using is **HeadlessChrome/109.0.5412.0**

I use the below configuration to launch the browser,

```
IBrowser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions{
      Headless = true,
      IgnoreHTTPSErrors = true,
      Timeout = 60000,
      Args: [
        "--enable-automation",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--disable-gpu", 
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage"
            ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PuppeteerSharp V10.0.0 has an open issue regarding this browser closing behavior. Please find more in the above issue [here](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/issues/2204).
Until the issue is resolves Recommend downgrading to a version to a more stabler version. etc V8.0.0

Comment: Thanks @selaka-nanayakkara
This seems to resolve the issue, I guess I have use the V8 for the time being.